# How can I change the host in my json file for Swagger Client depending on my Protractor spec?

Tags: json, protractor, swagger

I am using swagger client to test my REST. To run my tests on different environments I have different baseurls in the config files for Protractor. Is there a possibility to set the host in the json.file for Swagger Client to the baseUrl I use in my config file to Protractor? 
I hope someone understands I want to do! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure of Swagger Client Spec JSON format, but I am answering the generic question.

> ```
> How to update a JSON file & set the value in JSON file based on config.baseUrl before the test runs
> ```

There is something called `onPrepare()` option in [Protractor Config file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L391) which executes before the spec is run and Protractor global objects are available

Have the logic here to update your JSON here using `browser.baseUrl` here

```
 onPrepare: function() {
      var file_content = fs.readFileSync('spec.json');
      var content = JSON.parse(file_content);
      //Not sure of your JSON structure but this should work. Below example quotes simple structure
      content.url = browser.baseUrl;
      fs.writeFileSync('spec.json', JSON.stringify(content));
    },
```

Comment: Glad that it worked .. Can you mark it as answer to resolve the issue